# How to write a update query using Sql Compact Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I want to update column which has datatype of nvarchar. Want to change the column has identity column. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174123.aspx

It would be smth like

```
ALTER TABLE <IdentityTable> ALTER COLUMN <Identity Column> <Data Type> (1, 1)
```

But how're you going to add to nvarchar datatype indentity?